# componentWillReceiveProps not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'am updating the state **messages** and **id** of TalkContent and I'am trying to pass it to the appropriate child of Talks (which is itself a child of TalkContent).

**TalkContent**

```
class TalkContent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { talks : [], id : -1, messages : []};

    //
  }

  render(){
    if (this.state.id === -1)
    {
      return(
        <div className="TalksList">
            <Talks talks={this.state.talks} onTalkClick={this.onTalkClick} messages={this.state.messages} talkId={this.state.id} />
            //
        </div>
      )
    }
```

**Talks**

```
class Talks extends React.Component{

  render(){
    const talks = this.props.talks.map((talk, i) => {
      return (
        <Talk
          key={i}
          id={i}
          talk={talk.talk}
          username={talk.username}
          date={talk.date}
          onTalkClick={this.props.onTalkClick}
          messages={this.props.messages}
          talkId={this.props.talkId}
           />
      )
    });

    return(
      <div className="talkList">
        {talks}
      </div>

    )
  } //render
}
```

**Talk**

```
class Talk extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { messages : []};

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.props.username} : <span onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.talk}</span> {moment(this.props.date).fromNow()}
      </div>
    )
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(this.props.id === this.nextProps.talkId){
      this.setState({messages: nextProps.messages});
    }
  }
```

However, even when the states **messages** and **id** of TalkContent (the parent component) are updated, the function *componentWillReceiveProps* of Talk is never fired, in any of the childs. Can someone tell me what is wrong please?

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps is supposed to be placed before render(), I don't think it's gonna solver your problem. You don't declare your proptypes in your component, it's a bad practice too... You should use arrow function so no bind in constructor. In fact your constructors are all useless, you can declare state outside it.

Comment: I've placed it before render() but it's still the same. By declaring proptypes you mean typing **this.onTalkClick = this.onTalkClick.bind(this);** in the constructor? I've just omitted them make the code more readable.

Comment: To bind function in es6 you should use arrow function. Use 'static propTypes = { ... }' in your component. Look at facebook documentation. The fact you don't use the regular pratice is anoying when we are trying to help you.

Comment: Ok I'll take a look, but it doens't really relate to the problem I posed right?

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` fires only when props changes. In your case you have initial props with talkId | id set and doesn't change. You can reach talkId | id in `componentWillMount.`

Comment: @KeshShan But I have two props that changes, **messages** and **talkId**. They are updating through other functions that I have omitted in the code (They are truly updated, I can see that though a console.log(...)).

Comment: @Mit can you provide a jsfiddle with the not firing scenario

Comment: @KeshShan Sorry but what is a fiddle? ^^

Comment: can i see a running example of your not working scenario

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143177/discussion-between-mit-and-keshshan).

Answer (score 0):

I've quickly made a code sandbox that shows how a parent component can talk to a child component. If you open up Developer Tools > Console, you can see the props updating from both Parent and Child component. Hope it helps and feel free to ask any questions.

[Example for Mit](https://codesandbox.io/s/yPnNAwlxg)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143177/discussion-between-mit-and-keshshan). It seems props values were changed in the parent level(TalkContent Component) and props change was expected to fire in the Grand Child Component (Talk Component) through `componentWillReceiveProps` function.

`componentWillReceiveProps` gets normally fired within the child component if the props are changed in the parent component. So make-sure implementing  `componentWillReceiveProps` function should happen within parent-child hierarchy only

Comment: I don't think that's the case, I gave more details in the discussion can you take a look please?

Comment: All your answers should lie in my example. It's very linear and it shows how you should be approaching component design.

Answer (score -1):

React doesn't automatically rerender the component Talks if `this.props` are changed, you need to manually trigger a rerender using `this.forceUpdate()` or by setting state on it and updating that.

Comment: But componentWillReceiveProps is never called, if I place a console.log("test") in it (even before the "if"), the console stays empty.

Comment: "By default, when your component's state or props change, your component will re-render." React documentation. So what you are telling is incorrect

Comment: @kornflexx, ah, I thought he was setting them through `getInitialState`.

@mit, you have an `if` in the TalkContent component that blocks the render if the `id` is not `-1`

Comment: @Bogdan the 'if' is replaced by an 'else' after that renders something else, i've omitted it to make the code more readle but it doesn't have to do with the problem.